# Where is this Piyut from?

Tags: prayer-book

**What and Where is the original Hebrew of this piyut from?**

To the Oriental (Abraham) You revealed the future midnight of Passover.

At his door You knocked in the heat of the day on Passover.

He satiated the angels with matza-cakes on Passover.

And he ran to the herd—symbolic of the sacrificial beast of Passover.

The Sodomites provoked (God) and were destroyed by fire on Passover.

Lot was withdrawn from them, he had baked matzot at the time of Passover.

- Translation from Rabbi Avie Gold, The Complete Artscroll Machzor Pesach: Sefard

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The lines come from a *piyut* named *ometz gevurotecha hifleita bapesach* (or *uvchen va’amartem zevach pesach*) composed by R. Elazar HaKalir (often assumed to have lived in the 6/7th centuries CE) and recited today in the *ashkenazi* rite during the repetition of the *amidah* of *shacharit* on the second day of Pesach. (In addition, many have the custom to recite it after concluding the *seder* on the second night of Pesach.)

It can be found [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesach_Haggadah%2C_Nirtzah%2C_Zevach_Pesach.3?vhe=Pesach_Haggadah&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).